# I've created an extension, but when loaded can't find a dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, vscode-extensions

I've created an extension for VSCode which generated barrel files for Dart and Flutter projects.

I've used Javascript and I've used the package `loadash`. However, now that I have installed it, I keep getting the error: `Cannot find module 'lodash'`.

I've been looking around and I do not know how to fix it, since I would not want that all users should install the `loadash` dependency. Aren't dependecies added when created the extension package with `vsce package`?

Comment: Show you ˋpackage.json` please. Maybe you put the module to dev dependencies which is wrong.

Comment: I think I have fixed by removing `node_modules/**` from `.vscodeignore`

Comment: Yes, that can be a typical mistake. You can post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing the `node_modules/**` line from the `.vscodeignore` file.